How can i close mint feature?
Hi i made a spl token how can i add a feature that I can't mint tokens anymore
I following officiall document I faced with this part 
But as you see supply should be zero! for example i minted one million tokens but after that i want to can't mint more again

What you're seeing in there, is to actually close the mint account and reclaim the rent used to create the same.
What you are looking for is to revoke the mint authority of your mint account. By doing it, no more tokens will be minted
